# Find $\sin(\theta)$ when $\sin(\theta) > 0$, $\tan(\theta)=7/24$.

Tags: trigonometry

Find $\sin(\theta)$ when $\sin(\theta) > 0$, 
$\tan(\theta)=7/24$.

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: You're given the ratio between sine and cosine. Also the sum of their squares is one...

Comment: **Hint:** $\sec^2(x)=1+\tan^2(x)$ and $\sin(x)=\frac{\tan(x)}{\sec(x)}$

Comment: Please, 2 months later, select among the good answers by checking, the one that agrees you the most. It is by this little discipline that such a site can live and bring information to others.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

use $$\sin \theta ={\tan\theta\over \sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}}$$whenever $\sin \theta , \tan \theta \ge 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Draw a right triangle that shows $\tan \theta = 7/24.$  There are infinitely many, but choosing the one with legs $7$ and $24$ is a swell choice.   Now use Pythagorean Theorem to find the length of the hypotenuse.  Finding the values of any of the other trig functions should be easy now.

The only snag is that you have to think about which quadrant you're in.  But you have $\sin \theta$ and $\tan \theta$ both positive, so you're in the first quadrant.

Answer (score 2):

Use $\cos^2\theta = 1 - \sin^2\theta$ and $\tan\theta = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=c$. Then $\sin\theta = c\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$, then $\sin^2\theta = c^2-c^2\sin^2\theta$, and finally $\sin\theta = \frac{c}{\sqrt{1+c^2}}$. Note that when taking the roots I have taken the positive such since $\sin\theta>0$ and also $\tan\theta >0$, which implies $\cos\theta > 0$.